# Storing the output from a loop as a list in R

Tags: r, loops, random

I am running a small loop to randomly assign a list of numbers (1 to 30) to a subset of 4 groups. I would like to store the outputs of the loop (for 4 subsets) as a single line in one variable and use the results elsewhere. I am also getting some warnings, though the output is correctly displayed on the screen.

```
list = as.vector(c(6, 9, 3, 12)
start <- 1
end <- 6
i <- 1
while(i<=list){
  print(sample(start:end, replace=T))
  start <- start+list[i]
  end <- end + list[i+1]
  i <- i+1
}

[1] 3 5 6 1 5 6
[1]  9 13 12  7 11 12 14 11 14
[1] 16 17 17
 [1] 28 22 26 21 28 26 22 28 26 30 21 19
Error in start:end : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In while (i <= list) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In while (i <= list) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In while (i <= list) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In while (i <= list) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
5: In while (i <= list) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I am unable to find the reasons for this error. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: `Map(function(start, stop){sample(start:stop, replace = TRUE)}, cumsum(c(1,6,9,3)), cumsum(c(6,9,3,12)))`

Comment: I tried to initialise 'y <- NULL; temp <- sample(...), y < rbind(y,temp)'. I continue to get the above warnings. Furthermore, the output is trimmed to '4 x 6'.

Comment: Thanks @alistaire for your help. it still produces the output in four lines. I would prefer a single line output for two reasons: (1) The sample size and groupings are very large. Thus a single line output for groups in m  x n will be helpful. (2) The cumsum value in actual case would as a result will be bigger than this example; I am therefore looking to specify as a list, which can be controlled for m x n data sets. Thanks again.

Comment: the warnings are because `i<=list` compares i to every element of list and returns a logical vector. You probably ment `i<= length(list)`. But in any case, a while loop is not the way to go and you should use a vectorised approach as @alistaire suggested

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @dww. I will have a look.

Comment: @ diw. No. I did not mean 'length(list)'. The output returns a vector of numbers for every element in the list in one line than 4 lines for 4 elements. Thanks for your recommendation.

Comment: I wonder why does some one votes down this question. Who ever did it, they have a little idea of efforts I have put before posting this. Very helpful negative votes indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine using for loop than while loop, no need of sub-setting i variable when we use seq function

```
list = c(6, 9, 3, 12)
start <- 1
end <- 6

for(i in seq(list)){
  if(i <= list[i]){
     start <- start+list[i]
     end <- end + (list[i]+1)
  print(sample(start:end, replace=T))
  }

}

[1] 10  8 11  7 11 10 12
[1] 23 17 18 21 22 18 20 21
[1] 25 21 27 23 26 26 23 25 22
 [1] 33 32 37 37 35 40 32 37 34 38
```

Comment: @mysqlnew In your list you have 6,9,3,12 when you run a loop sub-setting i=1, at last iteration i have value 4 and i=i+1 becomes 5, where 5 is not less than or equal to 3 in your list so your will get error messages

Comment: Thanks Arun for the clarification. for loop would be a problem for a large sample size.

Comment: @mysqlnew Please vote up to my answer if you feel correct

Comment: Sorry. Although for loop eliminates the error, it does not help much. The list is used to generate 4 random number sets, which are not replaced between them. The output should be like my example for the list, but produced in one line. 3 5 6 1 5 6 9 13 12  7 11 12 14 11 14....Thanks for  your help but I am unable to vote your answer. @alistaire answer eliminates the warnings but still does not get the output in one line. Thanks every one for the help.

Comment: `x <- c(); x <- c(x, sample(start:end, replace=T))` gets the output in a single line.